# Does accessing location in foreground service is treated as accessing location in background?

Tags: android, location, foreground-service

My application is using location accessed in Foreground service. So will it be treated as location is accessed in background.

As foreground service runs on an application thread. While reviewing checklist of location access in background does not include the Foreground service. It does include IntentService.

Below is the checklist:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/background#checklist

Comment: This question is regarding a policy of the playstore, which could change at any time

Comment: Yes, but whether to submit the details or not. As for that they are expecting Disclosure dialog and then submit an update.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746

Comment: Yes, policies can be changed and this can is not related to policy. Modified my question. Need clarification on if accessing location foreground service is treated as location accessed in background. As i have not taken BACKGROUND_ACCESS permission from the user.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Whether something _is_ background location access is a technical question (hence there being a specific permission enforced by the system).  Whether a given use of background location access is permitted by Play Store policy is a separate question that doesn't appear to be being asked here.

Comment: @RyanM that's because this is no longer the same question as when i made my comment. you're welcome to review the original post which was here to determine whether or not it _was_ a policy question or not

Comment: @a_local_nobody ah, you're quite correct. My mistake. I probably should have checked more closely, given that I almost always agree with your voting and comments...

Comment: no worries @RyanM, the edits do change the question quite a bit so what you're saying definitely is valid